# Nokogiri: find tag, get attributes and replace tag

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm working with Nokogiri and I'm a newbye. I'm parsing an HTML document to match some  placeholder, and after match I must replace the widget placeholder with some generated HTML.

I create this method:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(raw)
matches = doc.xpath(".//widget")
if matches.present?
  matches.each do |match|
    media_replace(..)
else
  self.body = raw
end
```

I have some matches, and every match has this attributes.

```
 matches.first.attributes
{"data_id"=>#(Attr:0x3fdd42e2cebc { name = "data_id", value = "5" }),
"data_type"=>#(Attr:0x3fdd42e2ce94 { name = "data_type", value = "gallery" })}
```

How can I extract these attributes(gallery and 5) to pass them to my media_replace method?
Media_replace method return to me an 'html': how can I replace every 'match' with the returned HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get attribute values from a node you can use the [`[]` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D). For example:

```
media_replace(match['data_id'], match['data_gallery'])
```

To replace the node, use the [`replace`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-replace) or [`swap`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-swap) methods (assuming `media_replace` returns a string or other compatible object):

```
new_html = media_replace(...)
match.replace(new_html)
```

Comment: I want to create an html fragment to replace with Nokogiri, so I hope is a compatible object!!!

Comment: @RobertoPezzali it can be “a `Nokogiri::XML::Node`, a `::DocumentFragment`, a `::NodeSet`, or a string containing markup” – see the docs.